# Using fork() system call in unix using a c program

Tags: c, unix

Hey i want to know what will be output of following code:-

```
main()
{
fork();
fork();
fork();
printf("hello world");
}
```

I think it should print hello world 4 times.
Plz help me.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: No.it was asked in our mid-term exam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will print it 2^3=8 times. Remember, every time you call fork, you are creating a child process, that child process will continue the execution from right after it got forked so it can itself also fork. The tree will look like this.

```
                  First process.

  Forked1               Forked2       Forked3
```

Forked4---Forked5 -------------- Forked6

Forked7

So we will have total of 8 process (main process and 7 forked processes)running and printing the print statement. 
As a side note: if the print statement was before a fork, it would not get executed by newly forked process.

Answer (score 4):

it will print it 8 times (2 ^ 3): each fork generates an extra process -- so you end up with 2 processes at each step (the parent and the child) and each of them continue execution at the step right after the fork.
So first fork -> 2 processes each one of these going to 2nd fork in which you generate 2 extra processes so you have now 4 processes each going into the 3rd fork where each generates an extra process -- so 8 processes going into the line with printf!

Answer (score 2):

Each fork creates a new child. Each child has the same code as the parent. So the children will also fork.

So Parent has 3 children.
Child1 has 2 children.
Child2 has 1 child.
Child11 has 1 child.

Total 8 processes. 8 printf